# Sample example of box in latex

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

Could someone make this picture in sample code in LaTeX and please make it in different style with different colors.
[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
\fbox{
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
     This example will show you how we can ..
     $dX_{t}=b(t,X_{t})+\sigma (t,X_{t}) dW_{t}$
     \begin{center}
       \begin{tabular}{ l | c || r } \hline
         W & S  \\ \hline
         + & -  \\ \hline
       \end{tabular}
     \end{center}
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package a possibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the start of something that will create what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\shadowsize-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
   \textcolor{red}{\sffamily EXAMPLE 3.}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}

    \hspace*{\fill}
    %--------------------------%
    \setlength{\shadowsize}{2pt}
    \parbox{2in}{\shadowbox{$\displaystyle  dX_t = - \frac{1}{2X_t}I(X_t\not=)dt+dW_t$}}
    %--------------------------%
    \hspace*{\fill}
    %--------------------------%
    {\sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
     \textcolor{red}{W} & \textcolor{blue}{S} \\\hline
     $-$                & $-$                 \\\hline
    \end{tabular}}
    %-------------------------%
    \hspace*{\fill}\par\vspace{1ex}

\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want to color the box, I would recommend you look at the examples using `mdframed` given by @GonzaloMedina --- I'm not all that familiar with this package.  You might also consider looking at the package `tcolorbox` (also illustrated by GonzaloMedina), but it also seems to rely on the `tikz` bundle of packages and libraries.

Comment: Thaks so much work great but with (underfull \hbox badness 10000)

Comment: Hmmm. Not quite sure where that's coming from.  I'll look at that.

Comment: Fixed.  It was the use of `\\\`.  You shouldn't get the underfull box errors now.

Comment: Thanks Mr A.Ellett but still give me this time just one bad box error (overfull \hbox in paragraph at line334-335 ( \parbox{2in}{\shadowbox{$\displaystyle dX_t =-\frac{1}{2X_t}I(X_t\not=0)dt+dW_t$}} )

Comment: I fixed by change 2in to 3in Thanks my best to all of you

Comment: how can i make color inside minipage ??? i use \colorbox[HTML]{F8E0E0}{ } but donsen't wrok perectly guz it colored all minipage not insided it

Answer (score 12):

One option using the features provided by [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcounter{exa}

\tcbset{
myexample/.style={
  enhanced,
  colback=yellow!10!white,
  colframe=red!50!black,
  fonttitle=\scshape,
  titlerule=0pt,
  title={\refstepcounter{exa}example~\theexa.},
  title style={fill=yellow!10!white},
  coltitle=red!50!black,
  drop shadow,
  highlight math style={reset,colback=LightBlue!50!white,colframe=Navy}
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{texample}{myexample}

\begin{document}

\begin{texample}
\centering
\tcbhighmath{\textrm{d}X_{t}=b(t,X_{t})+\sigma (t,X_{t}) \textrm{d}W_{t}}\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textcolor{red!70!black}{W} & \textcolor{Navy}{C} \\
\hline
$+$ & $-$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{texample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's now an option using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcounter{exa}

\newmdenv[
settings={\refstepcounter{exa}},
linewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=1.5\baselineskip,
roundcorner=6pt,
backgroundcolor=yellow!10,
linecolor=red!70!black,
frametitle=example~\theexa,
frametitlefont=\scshape\color{red!70!black},
shadow=true
]{mdexample}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdexample}
\centering
\hfsetfillcolor{LightBlue!50}
\hfsetbordercolor{Navy}
\tikzmarkin{a}(0.3,0.6)(-0.3,-0.4)$\textrm{d}X_{t}=b(t,X_{t})+\sigma (t,X_{t}) \textrm{d}W_{t}$\tikzmarkend{a}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textcolor{red!70!black}{W} & \textcolor{Navy}{C} \\
\hline
$+$ & $-$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mdexample}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for ur code but gives error in package pgfkeys error:I do not know the key '/tcb/rest' and i am going to ignore it .prehpas you misspelled it

Comment: @Educ it's not "rest"; it is "reset".In any case, you need the most recent version of `tcolorbox` package: version 2.33 (2013/07/04).

Comment: Thanks Mr Gonzalo Medina can you give me the link to download it by the way i use texicenter with mitex

Comment: @Educ here's the [`link on CTAN`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox). MiKTeX has a package manager that can download it for you (unfortunately, I don't use MiKTeX, so I cannot tell you the exact instructions for the package manager, but here is some [`useful link`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html)).

Comment: Thanks i install it but still the same problem

Comment: @Educ besides installing you have to refresh the File Data Base (again, I don't know the details since I don't use MiKTeX). In any case, remove `reset` and that should solve the problem. Or also, see my updated answer for another option with `mdframed` and `hf-tikz`.

Comment: @Educ MikTeX got an update yesterday (maybe in the night) which includes the recent tcolorbox. I do not know if this update was available a few hours agp, so, please, try again to update MikTeX. This time it should work :-)

Comment: For the first example, based on ``tcolorbox``, I get an unexpected thin red horizontal line just below the title. Anyone else with this issue?